# ASW Billing and Storing Bill in Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, billing

In Amazon Cloud, I created a S3 bucket and configure S3 bucket for putting billing report. Then i create a daily billing report that will be inserted in the configured S3 bucket. I want to write a job in nodejs that will fetch the bill from S3 bucket daily and import it in to my database without duplicate lineitem (Uses mongoDB and mongoImport function for importing records from csv file to database). The problem is i didn't find a unique key for each lineitem so that i can't update my database daily.
**Sample Object:**

```
{   
    "identity/LineItemId" : "rm7ubabfqxwsmmutpeljlwx6bfckcandfk4di77zjvspx36aohvq",
    "identity/TimeInterval" : "2017-03-03T00:00:00Z/2017-03-04T00:00:00Z",
    "bill/InvoiceId" : "",
    "bill/BillingEntity" : "AWS",
    "bill/BillType" : "Anniversary",
    "bill/PayerAccountId" : "123",
    "bill/BillingPeriodStartDate" : "2017-03-01T00:00:00Z",
    "bill/BillingPeriodEndDate" : "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z",
    "lineItem/UsageAccountId" : "123",
    "lineItem/LineItemType" : "Usage",
    "lineItem/UsageStartDate" : "2017-03-03T03:00:00Z",
    "lineItem/UsageEndDate" : "2017-03-03T21:00:00Z",
    "lineItem/ProductCode" : "AmazonS3",
    "lineItem/UsageType" : "Requests-Tier1",
    "lineItem/Operation" : "PutObject",
    "lineItem/AvailabilityZone" : "",
    "lineItem/ResourceId" : "Bucket Name",
    "lineItem/UsageAmount" : 44.0000000000000000,
    "lineItem/CurrencyCode" : "USD",
    "lineItem/UnblendedRate" : 0.0000050000000000,
    "lineItem/UnblendedCost" : 0.0002200000000000,
    "lineItem/BlendedRate" : 0.0000050000000000,
    "lineItem/BlendedCost" : 0.0002200000000000,
    "lineItem/LineItemDescription" : "$0.005 per 1,000 PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST requests",
    "lineItem/TaxType" : "",
    "product/ProductName" : "Amazon Simple Storage Service",
    "product/availability" : "",
    "product/durability" : "",
    "product/fromLocation" : "",
    "product/fromLocationType" : "",
    "product/group" : "S3-API-Tier1",
    "product/groupDescription" : "PUT/COPY/POST or LIST requests",
    "product/location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
    "product/locationType" : "AWS Region",
    "product/maxIopsBurstPerformance" : "",
    "product/maxIopsvolume" : "",
    "product/maxThroughputvolume" : "",
    "product/maxVolumeSize" : "",
    "product/operation" : "",
    "product/productFamily" : "API Request",
    "product/servicecode" : "AmazonS3",
    "product/sku" : "E9YHNFENF4XQBZR6",
    "product/storageClass" : "",
    "product/storageMedia" : "",
    "product/toLocation" : "",
    "product/toLocationType" : "",
    "product/transferType" : "",
    "product/usagetype" : "Requests-Tier1",
    "product/volumeType" : "",
    "pricing/publicOnDemandCost" : 0.0002200000000000,
    "pricing/publicOnDemandRate" : 0.0000050000000000,
    "pricing/term" : "OnDemand",
    "pricing/unit" : "Requests",
    "reservation/TotalReservedUnits" : "",
    "reservation/UnitsPerReservation" : "",
    "resourceTags/aws:createdBy" : ""
}
```

Comment: The unique key will be a composite key spanning multiple columns, including services and regions and dates if I remember correctly.  Which report is this, exactly?

Comment: below i am posting one sample object that i am storing in my mongo database using mongoimport function

Comment: It is AWS Report with time unit as Daily and include                       Resource IDs,                                                                                  Account identifiers
Invoice and Bill Information
Usage Amount and Unit
Rates and Cost
Product Attributes (e.g., instance type, operating system, and region)
Pricing Attributes (e.g., offer types, and lease lengths)
Reservation identifiers and related details (for reserved instances only)

Comment: This isn't the format I was thinking of, but wouldn't it be the first two columns?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you find a way of how to insert without duplicate lineitemID @mich

Comment: @xhiza I believe you will find that `identity/LineItemId` isn't intended to be unique; you need to combine that with `identity/TimeInterval` so that you have a two-column ("composite") primary key.  If you still encounter duplicates, this *should* mean that you're looking at two copies of the same exact record, but you should verify that.